# jQuery $.when fires before done completion

Tags: jquery

I have the following code that isn't working properly.

$.when, returns immediately, long before the actions in `.done` are completed. How can I defer actions until `.done` is completed?

```
var getReturn = function() {
  $.post("/app/return.php", { auth: auth })
  .done(function(data) {
      // Does some calculations, does not return values 
  }); 
} 

$.when(getReturn())
.done(function(response1) {
   console.log('fire');
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you need to return the promise returned by `$.post` from `getReturn()`

```
var getReturn = function() {
    return $.post("/app/return.php", { auth: auth })
    .done(function(data) {
        // Does some calculations, does not return values 
    }); 
}
```

Comment: @kylex there is a `return` keyword before `$.post`